# django username-related URL resolution fails when username has odd characters

Tags: python, django

So, the default Django `User` model allows usernames to have a few weird characters - e.g. I can make a user called '@.+-_'. However, I've made a user profile page whose url is dependent on username. I'd like to use the username instead of user_id because it's more readable:

```
url(r'^public_profile/(?P<username>[\w\d]+)$', 
    views.public_profile, 
    name='public_profile'),
```

This works fine for most users, but when a user with a funky name - e.g. '@.+-_' is looked up, the public_profile page fails with a

```
Reverse for 'public_profile' with arguments '('@.+-_',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['public_profile/(?P<username>[\\w\\d]+)$']
```

error. --> So, I figured I could add a 'slug' field to the `User` model, and use that plus the user_id in the url (so slugs don't accidentally collide), but I'm not sure how to modify the `User` model since it's part of django. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than altering the model, you should alter the URL so that it doesn't fail. The problem is your regex: `\w\d` matches alphanumeric characters only (in fact `\w` does that already, the `\d` is superfluous). You could add the specific characters you want to match:

```
r'^public_profile/(?P<username>[+-@_.\w]+)$'
```

or just match everything:

```
r'^public_profile/(?P<username>.+)$'
```

Comment: Man. I know comments aren't supposed to be used for thank-yous... But you just saved me a *lot* of wasted time! I was focusing on the wrong thing entirely. +10 Great answer.